# Lock a cell using FormulaR1C1

Tags: excel, vba

I am wondering if it is possible to lock a cell reference using vba.

Here is my code

```
Sub Practice()
Dim myValue As Variant

'Get Input Value
myValue = InputBox("Input")

'Insert a Row
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).EntireColumn.Insert

'Select Blank Cell in New Column
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select

'Formula
ActiveCell.Value = myValue
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=.25*$R[-1]$C[0]*R[0]C[-1]"


End Sub
```

I would like the formula in the cell to read "=.25*$B$1*A2" (assuming B2 is the cell it is being put into)

Comment: you can use `.Range`

Comment: Do you mind posting an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid using `.Select`.

Also to make a relative cell absolute, without knowing the cell before hand, you can just pass the address of that cell to the formula.

Also you need to make sure the input is a number and not a text string:

```
Sub Practice()
Dim myValue As Variant

'Get Input Value
Do
myValue = InputBox("Input")
If Not IsNumeric(myValue) Then MsgBox "Input must ba a number"
Loop Until IsNumeric(myValue)


'Insert a Row
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).EntireColumn.Insert

'Select Blank Cell in New Column
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = myValue
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=.25*" & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Address(1, 1, xlR1C1) & "*R[0]C[-1]"


End Sub
```

If your cell is always B1 then you can use `R1C2` in place of `" & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Address(1, 1, xlR1C1) & "`

Comment: Thanks Scott! That works great and simplifies a few things!